# Notation of inverse trigonometric functions and exponentiation

Tags: trigonometry, notation, exponentiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\arcsin$ written as $\sin^{-1}(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30317/arcsin-written-as-sin-1x)

I have worked a bit on trigonometry today, and something strikes me as inconsistent.

In the book, the notation for the inverse sine function is $\sin^{-1}$, but the same notation is also used in $\sin^2$ meaning $(\sin x)^2$.

*Are there any alternate notations which avoid this ambiguity?*

**Some examples:**

$\sin30^\circ = 0.5$
$\sin^2 30^\circ = (\sin 30^\circ)^2 = 0.25$

However, inverse sine does not work that way:
$\sin^{-1} 30^\circ \ne (\sin 30^\circ)^{-1}$
$\sin^{-1} 30^\circ = $ *Error or complex number?*
$(\sin 30^\circ)^{-1} = 2$

The potential confusion only gets worse if you use **radians**, as they are in the range [-1, 1] for [-57°, 57°].:

$\sin^{-1} 0.524 = 0.551$
$(\sin 0.524)^{-1} = 2$

And what if you want *both at the same time*? You are forced to use parentheses, thus breaking any consistency: $(\sin^{-1} x)^2$

Comment: $\arcsin$ instead of $\sin^{-1}$

Comment: Indeed it is unfortunate notation.  And the better ($\arcsin$) notation is gradually gettiing less common, $\sin^{-1}$ is easier to squeeze on a calculator keyboard.

Comment: It's interesting that in Serbia we never used $sin^{-1}$ and I got kinda confused when I seen that notation everywhere around the world. We learned $arc$s only. So as people already said, $arcsin$ could solve your problem. (It's also interesting we use $tg$ for $tan$ and $ctg$ for $cot$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse trigonometric functions are also called arcfunctions, as they return the unit circle arc length (in radians) for a particular value of sine, cosine, etc.

$$\sin^{-1}(x)=\arcsin x$$
$$\cos^{-1}(x)=\arccos x$$

Comment: Is *asin* acceptable an abbreviation for *arcsin*? It is used a lot in programming languages.

Comment: @CheeseSucker: I've seen those labels on the buttons on HP calculators, but I don't know that I've ever seen them in mathematical writing.

Answer (score 3):

Carl Gauss also objected to this particular notational inconsistency, so you're in good company.  He proposed that $\sin^2(x)$ ought to mean $\sin(\sin(x))$, whereas $(\sin x)^2$ should be written in that way.

But the notation in the book you mention is standard.  I don't think there's any standard alternative.