# Graph $y=1/\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Graph $y=\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$

Now, I looked at the graph on google and got this [image: y=1\sin(x)]

Which I thought that $y=\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$ would be $y=\sin^{-1}x$ But it's apparently not. So if anyone can shed some light on this. It's not just about finding a graph and copying it. I would like a better understanding of this. Also, I know the format for graphing trig functions is $y=a\sin k(x+c)+d$. But I don't understand how to  fit the OP into this.
**Edit:**
So, the OP is $y=(\sin x)^{-1}$ or the inverse of $\sin x$. Now, all I need help with is how to graph accordingly.

Comment: $\sin^{-1} x$ is one of those poor notations given that, for example, $\sin^2 x = (\sin x)^2$. $\sin^{-1} x$ means the inverse sine of $x$ (_i.e._ $\arcsin x$), not $1/\sin x$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. But how would I graph this? Using the given equation. But I also thought that $\dfrac{1}{x}=x^{-1}$ Thus, $\dfrac{1}{\sin x}=\sin^{-1}x$

Comment: aka $\text{arcsin}.$

Comment: Right, so back to the OP; $y=\dfrac{1}{\sin x}=\arcsin x$, right? But, if that's the case. Then those two equations are two different graphs

Comment: It's true that $1/x=x^{-1}$, but that implies that $\frac{1}{\sin{x}}=(\sin{x})^{-1}$, which is not the same as $\sin^{-1}(x)$, which is just a *notation* for $\arcsin$ (or viceversa), which is the inverse function of the sine function. The quid here is that "the inverse function $f^{-1}$ to a function $f$ is not computed in some value $x$ as the multiplicative inverse to the value $f(x)$, that is: it is not true that $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$. In particular, it is not true for the sine function.

Comment: So, $y=\dfrac{1}{\sin x}=\arcsin x$?

Comment: No, $\arcsin(x)$ is by definition some $t$ such that $\sin(t) = x$.  This is not at all the same as $\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}$, which is $y$ such that $y \sin(x) = 1$.  It's just that the notation $f^{-1}$, where $f$ is the name of a function, is interpreted as the inverse function, whereas $x^{-1}$, where $x$ is a number, is the reciprocal.

Comment: Oh, okay. So $y=\dfrac{1}{\sin x}=(\sin x)^{-1}$. But how would I graph that is my next problem.

Comment: For further notes on the confusing notation, see [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30317).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer supposes the OP actually wants to plot $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, not $\arcsin(x)$.*

HINT: what is the value of the sine function on $\dots, -2\pi, -\pi, 0,\pi, 2\pi, \dots$ and on $\dots, -3\pi/2,-\pi/2,\pi/2,3\pi/2,\dots$? What's its behavior in between these points (positive/negative, increasing/decreasing)?

This is a craftman's hint to the question, which exploits the fact that we know exactly how $\sin(x)$ behaves.

If we are more clever, we can also exploit another fact of the sine function, the fact that it is *periodic*. You know that $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. This allows you to plot the sine function just on $[0,2\pi)$ and then "copy it" appropiately to get the graph on all $\mathbb{R}$.

We can exploit this in this case too, since $\frac{1}{\sin(x+2\pi)}=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ whenever $\sin(x)$ doesn't vanish. This means that, to plot $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, you might just as well plot it on the points of $[0,2\pi]$ where it is defined, and then copy the graph appropiately. This might make it easier, and puts on paper what you surely observed the moment you looked at the graph, that is, it is the same on $[-2\pi,0]$ and on $[0,2\pi]$.

---

There is another approach which is more mechanical and uses calculus:

HINT: Find out where the function is defined. At the points where it is not defined, find out the lateral limits. Now what calculus tool lets you find out if a function is increasing/decreasing? Compute it, and you will also find the local maxima/minima.

Comment: So, you're saying plot the points of all the sine functions and then connect the dots in a sense?

Comment: @Austin: I believe you meant to say "plot the sine of all those points", which is not quite the same. Well, plotting some crucial points is never enough to plot a function (you could "connect the dots" in so many different ways!), but that is the purpose of my second question. If you know the value of the function on some points, *and* you know the behavior of the function in between, you can then make a reasonable plot.

Comment: I mean like, how $\sin (2\pi)=0$ I would then put a dot there? and so on. But that wouldn't seem to work. Your second question about the behavior. Can you elaborate on the question without giving the answer, I need to try and figure this out myself! Thanks.

Comment: Be careful! You're not plotting $\sin(x)$ but $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$. If $\sin(2\pi)=0$, then what happens with $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ in $2\pi$?

Comment: Now, this can be a problem considering this is a calculus assignment when I have not taken the course yet and also, I skipped pre-calculus. So I'm trying to answer this question with only trigonometry skills. Which is probably why I'm completely confused. And would that make it $(-2\pi)$?

Comment: @Austin: Then stick to the first hint which uses no calculus, only knowledge of the sine function. The second hint is just another way to solve the same problem. Now, I ask you this (very related) question: is the function $\frac{1}{x}$ defined in 0?

Comment: What do you mean by is the function $\frac{1}{x}$ defined in $0$

Comment: @Austin, do you know how to plot the function $\frac{1}{x}$? Do you know what the [domain of definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_definition) of a function is?

Comment: Yes, I know what $\frac{1}{x}$ looks like, and I know what domain is. For instance the domain for $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is $[x \in \mathbb R]$. Because in the graph for $\sqrt[3]{x}$ it will eventually cover the $x$ until infinity.

Comment: @Austin: Yes, that is right. The question is then, is 0 in the domain of $1/x$? Or to put it differently, can you divide 1 by 0?

Comment: No, you can't divide by $0$. The graph will reach infinity just to the right of $x=0$. If I'm not mistaken. So no, you can not divide by zero because you will get undefined.

Comment: @Austin: that's right. Now, I ask again: is $\frac{1}{\sin(2\pi)}$ defined?

Comment: No. Let's see, considering $2\pi =360$ which is also $0$. That would be a no. Are you trying to say that $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{x}$? But only when $x=0$?

Comment: @Austin: I was just leading you to see that $\frac{1}{\sin(2\pi)}$ is not defined, because $\sin(2\pi)=0$ and $1/0$ is not defined. Now back to the question at hand: you know that in $2\pi$ your function is not defined. What about $\dots, -2\pi,0,4\pi,\dots$?

Comment: Oh, alright. And let's see. $$\sin(-2\pi)=0$$ $$\sin(0)=0$$ $$\sin(4\pi)=0$$

Comment: @Austin: Right. So in those points, $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ is not defined. Now try to continue through by yourself.

Comment: $$\sin(\pi )=0$$ $$\sin\left(-\frac{3\pi }{2}\right)=1$$ $$\sin\left(\frac{3\pi }{2}\right)=-1$$ $$\sin\left(-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=-1$$ $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=1$$

Comment: @Austin: Very true. I updated my answer to reflect the fact (which you surely already observed) that the sine function is *periodic*, and how you can exploit that.

Comment: So the period of this graph is every $\pi$?

Comment: I got it now, and I understand everything. Thank you so much for taking your time to help me!

Comment: @Austin: you're welcome, I'm glad you understood :)

Comment: Me too. And sorry for the questions. It's just hard to relate with not taking pre-calc and jumping straight to calculus. I also just like to KNOW how to do things. Not just the answers!

Answer (score 4):

Just to put it all in one place:

if there were any justice, nobody would ever say
$$
\sin^{-1}(x).
$$

They would say
$$
\arcsin(x)
$$
if they meant the inverse of the sine function, and
$$
\frac{1}{\sin(x)}
$$
if they meant the reciprocal of the sine function.

Because there is no justice, there's a horrible rule that $\sin^{-1}(x)$ means the inverse and not the reciprocal. This makes no sense becuase $\sin^2(x)$ means the square of the sine function. This unnecessarily confuses students who are already often confused about the difference between an inverse and a reciprocal. It's just... it's just the worst. I need to go drink a glass of water, I'm foaming at the mouth a little.

Comment: Of course, you then have those people who use $\log^2 x$ to denote the 2-fold iterate of the logarithm, $\log\log\,x$. Oh, notation...

Answer (score 2):

The notation is a bit misleading. Instead of $\dfrac1{\sin(x)}$ (the reciprocal of the sine), what $\sin^{-1}(x)$ means is the [arcsine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions), the [inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of sine.