# What is the domain of $f(x) = \ln(1+x)^{\sin(x)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Wolfram Alpha says that the domain of 
$$f(x) = \large \ln(1+x)^{\sin(x)}$$

is $x \gt 0$. I can't figure out how we come up with this restrictions. Please help.

Comment: If Wolfram Alpha told you that, it is wrong.

Comment: How come you say that? Is there something I should know about?!

Comment: By $\ln^{\sin(x)}(1+x)$, do you mean
$$\big(\;\ln(1+x)\;\big)^{\sin(x)}\qquad ?$$

Comment: @GeorgeF-bot Nevermind, apparently I misread the function. I can't even understand what function it is.

Comment: @ZevChonoles yes. Any clues?

Comment: @George F-bot: I am confused what you mean, see [**WA Plot**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+Log%5B%281%2Bx%29%5ESin%5Bx%5D%5D).

Comment: @GeorgeF-bot: It is incorrect to write powers that way. Even though it is a convention for trigonometric functions, it is a *terrible* convention ([see the confusion it can cause here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30317/264)), and at any rate does not apply to any other functions whatsoever.

Comment: @GeorgeF-bot: Are you considering $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ domains? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, can you please address him by "GeorgeF-bot"? Otherwise, I get the notification instead. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we agree on having *positive* bases for exponential functions, it thus must be

$$\log(1+x)>0\Longleftrightarrow 1+x>1\Longleftrightarrow x>0\,$$

just as WA said...

Comment: What about when $x = -\pi$? Technically, $f(-\pi) = 1$ (because $(a+bi)^0 = 1$).

Comment: If $x = -\pi$, then $1+x = 1-\pi < 0$, so its logarithm is not even defined.

Comment: No, then its logarithm is complex ($\ln(1 - \pi) \approx 0.7615 + i\pi$), and $\sin(-\pi) = 0$, and $(0.7615 + i\pi)^0 = 1$. Do we deal with this case when discussing domains?

Comment: That's a stretch, @GeorgeV.Williams: unless specifically asked by the OP, we always assume the "usual" functions are real ones. In particular here, the usual notation for the complex logarithm is "Log" and not "log" or even less, as the OP wrote, "ln".

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks for clearing that up for me.