# What is the order of operations in trig functions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Is $\sin(x)^2$ the same as $\sin^2(x)$ or $\sin(x^2)$? I thought it would mean the former interpretation, $\sin^2(x)$, rather than the latter, but my teacher and I had a long argument on this and in the end I found that Casio calculators have a space between before the parenthesis, so it would look like $\sin\text{ }(x)^2$ and what the calculator would do is calculate $x^2$, and then take the $\sin$ of that whereas on Texas calculators, there is no space, so it would look like $\sin(x)^2$ and it will calculate $\sin$ of $x$ first, and then take the result and square it.

Comment: There is no "correct" interpretation when it comes to notation. That is why it is important to use standard notations or to clarify what you mean by a non-standard notation. Indeed, $\sin^2 (x)$ usually denotes $(\sin x)^2$, while $\sin(x)^2$ is often viewed as nonstandard.

Comment: Also see [meaning of powers on trig functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172760/139123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Large \sin(x)^2 \equiv [\sin(x)]^2 \equiv \sin^2(x).$$

Think about it: if $\sin(x)^2$ were equivalent to $\sin(x^2),$ then the exponent $\quad ^2 \quad$ would be inside the brackets.

Comment: That x was just a condensed version of the original expression that we were arguing on. The original one was x+a. And what about the difference for Texas and Casio calculators? Does the space really mean that difference?

Comment: So, is Sin (X*X) same as (Sin X)*(Sin X)?

Comment: And now, what is it without brackets: $\sin x^2$ ... ??

Comment: @Muhatashim I don't know about all calculators, but as far as mathematical convention goes, $\sin(x^2)$ is interpreted as in my answer, and spacing makes **no** difference.

Comment: @RaoA. No. the former is $\sin(x^2)$ (i.e. the sine of the square of $x$) and the latter is is $[\sin(x)]^2$ (i.e. the square of the sine of $x$). The two are **not** (necessarily the same).

Comment: @GEdgar If there are no brackets, when in doubt, assume that everything after the $\sin$ is to be bracketed. i.e. assume that $\sin x^2 \equiv \sin (x^2)$.

Comment: "if $\sin(x)^2$ were equivalent to $\sin(x^2),$ then the exponent $\quad ^2 \quad$ would be inside the brackets." unless you interpret $\sin(x)^2$ as equivalent to $\sin((x)^2)$

Answer (score 1):

If you see $(\sin{x})^{2}$, to me this means $(\sin{x})(\sin{x})$.  Mathematicians are **lazy** and don't like writing parentheses around the $\sin{x}$ every time when squaring it, so they decided to write $\sin^{2}{x}$ when they want to square $\sin{x}$.

So basically, yes, $\sin^{2}{x} = (\sin{x})^{2}$.

In fact, for any whole number $n \geq 2$, when we write $\sin^{n}{x}$, we really mean $(\sin{x})^{n}$.

**There is one exception.**

$\sin^{-1}{x} \neq (\sin{x})^{-1}$.

This is because we write $\sin^{-1}{x}$ for the inverse function of $\sin{x}$ (in other words, $\sin^{-1}{x}$ is what we write for $\arcsin{x}$).

However, $(\sin{x})^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sin{x}} = \csc{x}$.  And if you know your trig functions well, you will know $\arcsin{x}$ and $\csc{x}$ are not the same functions.  So with $-1$, $\sin^{-1}{x}$ is a different function from $(\sin{x})^{-1}$.

Answer (score -1):

It is not only in trigonometric functions, all functions fall under this notation. $$(f(x))^2 \equiv f(x)^2 \equiv f^2(x)$$
It is commonly used for trigonometric functions and logarithmic ones, but it doesn't mean it is wrong for the rest of functions.

Comment: I've seen the iterated logarithm $\log(\log x)$ written as $\log^2 x$. So it's not completely universal convention of interpreting $f^2(x)$ as $f(x)^2$ rather than $(f\circ f)(x)$.

Comment: @Semiclassical True, though I usually see the exponent in brackets when indicating composition, e.g. $f^2(x) = (f(x))^2$ and $f^{(2)}(x) = (f \circ f)(x) = f(f(x))$. It should hopefully be clear from context in most cases though.

Comment: Aye, though that overlaps with $f^{(n)}(x)$ as the $n$th derivative, though. Furthermore, if one writes differentiation as an operator $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ then the usual notation is $f^{(n)}(x)=D^n f(x)$. So it all comes down to conventions... @Thomas

Comment: @Semiclassical Agreed, in case of ambiguity always define your terms and there will be no problem :)