# I'm trying to differentiate this function but I am getting conflicting answers on different sites

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$f(x) = \sin (1 - 2x)^³$

Is $\sin(1-2x)^³$ same as $\sin^³(1-2x)$?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: This form $\sin (1 - 2x)^3$ for $ \sin^3 (1 - 2x)$ should be avoided, we can use as an alternative $(\sin (1 - 2x))^3$.

Comment: Please refer to my explanation at [What does $\operatorname{trig}(x)^n$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4058720/21813). The short answer is that some of us actively avoid $\sin(x)^n$ for being, at best, unnecessarily ambiguous, even as many people consider $\sin(x)^n$ and $\sin^n(x)$ as synonyms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to be careful with the parentesis. Note that $$\sin^3(1-2x)=\sin (1-2x)\cdot \sin (1-2x)\cdot \sin (1-2x),$$ and $$\sin (1-2x)^3$$ is a little ambigous, it should  be written as $$\sin \left((1-2x)^3\right)=\sin \left((1-2x)\cdot (1-2x)\cdot (1-2x)\right),$$ which is clearly not the same.