A question about notation with a functional equation
A friend posted a series of casual math problems, including the following one which has been driving me up the wall:
$$f(t) = \frac{t-1}{t+1}\\
t \in \mathbb{R}-\{0,-1,1\}\\
f^{n+1}(t) = f(f^n(t))\\
n \in \mathbb{N}\\
x = f^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+f^9(9)f^8(10)$$
I am NOT looking for an answer nor for help solving the problem itself, I just want to know how to interpret the line
$$f^{n+1}(t) = f(f^n(t))$$
I had thought that the superscripts were functionally similar to subscripts for a sequence - e.g. $f^2(t)$, $f^3(t), etc$ would be analogous to $a_2, a_3,...$ That raises the question of whether the initial statement of f(t) would be $f_0(t)$ or $f_1(t)$. I suspect I'm interpreting this notation incorrectly (for instance whether it should be read the same as $(f(t))^2$ ).
None of the ways I've interpreted the question have yielded good results, and it's frustrating not knowing whether I'm just not reading the problem correctly. It has been quite a while since I've been in school so I don't have any reference at hand. I must be using the wrong search terms because nothing has turned up. Any illumination would be greatly appreciated.

Generally, $f^n(x)$ should be interpreted as one would $(f(x))^n$, much like how one does with $\sin x$ ($\sin^n x$) or $\ln x$ ($\ln^n x$), i.e., it should be representative of exponentiation. Some choose to instead use it for iterated composition, i.e. $f^3(x) = (f \circ f \circ f)(x)$. Part of me thinks that line your concerned about may be stating a constraint; another part of me thinks it might be stating a definition or convention. It'd be hard to know without asking the source though.

It's composition of functions: $f^2(t)=f(f(t)), f^3(t)=f(f^2(t))=f(f(f(t))),$ etc.

Thank you very much! It's a real relief to put this to bed.

Also relevant, particularly in light of @PrincessEev's comment, is https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4663489/468350 .
