# Raising functions to powers

Tags: trigonometry

I have learned that sin²(x) = (sin x)².
Why does it not generalize such that sin⁻¹(x) = (sin x)⁻¹?

P.S. I understand that they are not equal, sin⁻¹(x) is arcsin x, but (sin x)⁻¹ is csc x.

**EDIT:** What would sin⁻²(x) be?

Comment: This is just an unfortunate choice of notation I'm afraid.  There's not a logical reason, really, just two different, contradictory meanings for $k$ in the notation $\sin^{k}(x)$.

Comment: You need to use context clues to see which is meant.  I prefer writing $\arcsin$ for this reason.

Comment: Does this mess apply to all functions?

Comment: I found a similar discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117986/why-is-arcsin-represented-with-the-1-notation but I couldn't find a clear answer how to know what would be intended by something combining both such as sin⁻²(x)

Comment: It just depends on context.  Sometimes authors use $f^k$ to mean the pointwise product, and sometimes they use it to mean the composition $f \circ f \circ \ldots \circ f$ ($k$ times), e.g. in a permutation group.  But hopefully the two notations are not used on the same set in the same chapter/article...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's just like natural languages, and this is just an annoying exception. While I don't know what the edge case of a negative power that is not 1, I understand that the two notations don't play nicely, and aren't related.