# Is $\tan^{-1}$ for $\arctan$ on my calculator wrong?

Tags: calculator

On my calculator $\tan^{-1}$ is used to calculate the $\arctan$, but $\tan^{-1}$ actually is $\cot$. $\cot$ and $\arctan$ are not the same thing though. Am I missing something or is the labeling of my Casio fx-991ES really wrong?

To make the question more clear: Is $\arctan = \tan^{-1}$ correct?

Comment: *All* calculators I know, among them the Casio ones, use $\;\tan^{-1}\;$ to denote $\;\arctan\;$ , **not** $\;\cot\;$ ..

Comment: What do you get when you punch in $\tan^{-1}(1)$ or $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: I have that one besides me and it is working fine, except the fact that you keep record whether the measurement of angles is set in degrees or radians.

Comment: I have a 991-MS, same story. It's not wrong. It's just inverse notation of a function.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30317/arcsin-written-as-sin-1x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calculators have to save space on the labels, therefore $\tan^{-1}$ is more convenient than $\arctan$.

Moreover, the notation $f^{-1}$ conventionally denotes the functional inverse of $f$. It's rare to write $f^{-1}$ meaning $1/f$.

On my calculator, for example, $\sin^{-1}$ and $\cos^{-1}$ are used in place of the more correct (in my opinion, since less confusing) $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$.

Comment: So you're saying $\tan^{-1}$ is not *wrong* but not exactly correct either? Mathematically speaking...

Comment: @Stacksatty: Exactly. It's an established convention, but unfortunately it overlaps with other notations, thereby generating confusion. It's the reason I much prefer the arc-functions, as they have an unique and explicit meaning.

Answer (score 4):

The notation $\tan^{-1}$ is often reserved for the canonical functional inverse of the $\tan$ version rather than its reciprocal. You're right that it's confusing, but that's the conventional mathematical notation.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is ambiguous, but the reason for that is that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse element of $f$ by composition law ($(f \circ f)(x) = f(f(x))$ :
$$f \circ f^{-1} = \text{id}$$
Where id is the identity function, the neutral of $(F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}), \circ)$.